# Why name column in table repeats itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

hello i have been working on this query since many days and finally almost done with it except 1 problem.

It gives me this output

```
N   ConductorName   Denomination    totaltransactions   totalamount
1   NULL               NULL              1882             41610.00
1   Imran              30.00             199              5970.00
2   NULL               Imran total       199              5970.00
1   Shoaib             30.00             99               2970.00
2   NULL               Shoaib total      99               2970.00
1   Umair              10.00             792              7920.00
2   Umair              15.00             396              5940.00
3   Umair              30.00             99               2970.00
4   Umair              40.00             99               3960.00
5   Umair              60.00             198              11880.00
6   NULL               Umair total       1584             32670.00
```

it fine but i want to eliminate name repetition in ConductorName column i.e.

Expected:

```
N   ConductorName   Denomination    totaltransactions   totalamount
1   NULL               NULL              1882             41610.00
1   Imran              30.00             199              5970.00
2   NULL               Imran total       199              5970.00
1   Shoaib             30.00             99               2970.00
2   NULL               Shoaib total      99               2970.00
1   Umair              10.00             792              7920.00
2   NULL               15.00             396              5940.00
3   NULL               30.00             99               2970.00
4   NULL               40.00             99               3960.00
5   NULL               60.00             198              11880.00
6   NULL               Umair total       1584             32670.00
```

so every name 1 time but data intact.

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportConductorPerformance]
@FromDate DATE,
@ToDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name order by c.name) 'N',CASE WHEN isnull(CAST(T .amount AS varchar(30)), c.name + ' total') LIKE '%total%' THEN NULL ELSE c.name END AS ConductorName, 
                             ISNULL(CAST(T.Amount AS varchar(30)), c.Name + ' total') AS Denomination, COUNT(*) AS totaltransactions, SUM(T.Amount) AS totalamount
    FROM            dbo.Tickets AS T INNER JOIN
                             Transport.Conductors AS c ON c.ConductorID = T.Conductor_ID
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ServerDateTime) BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
    GROUP BY c.Name, T.Amount WITH ROLLUP 
END
```

Comment: @Blam sorry what does that mean ? and what should be i afraid of >

Answer (score 0):

While I wouldn't recommend handling this in the database, you could utilize the `case` statement to achieve your results since you're already using `row_number`:

```
SELECT N, 
       case when N = 1 then ConductorName else NULL end ConductorName, 
       Denomination, 
       totaltransactions, 
       totalamount
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name order by c.name) 'N',
        CASE WHEN isnull(CAST(T.amount AS varchar(30)), c.name + ' total') LIKE '%total%' 
             THEN NULL
             ELSE c.name 
        END AS ConductorName, 
        ISNULL(CAST(T.Amount AS varchar(30)), c.Name + ' total') AS Denomination, 
        COUNT(*) AS totaltransactions, 
        SUM(T.Amount) AS totalamount
    FROM dbo.Tickets AS T INNER JOIN
            Transport.Conductors AS c ON c.ConductorID = T.Conductor_ID
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ServerDateTime) BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
    GROUP BY c.Name, T.Amount WITH ROLLUP 
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can use the existing CASE statement with a simplified condition only keeping the name for the first row within your partition.  Also, if you leave out the 'ELSE' the value will be NULL by default, a slight simplification.

Another slight simplification is to use SQL Server's grouping method to detect your extra rows instead of watching for values that are NULL.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name order by c.name) 'N',
    CASE
        WHEN T.amount IS NOT NULL AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name order by c.name) = 1 THEN c.name
        END AS ConductorName,
    CASE
        WHEN grouping(T.Amount) = 0 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), T.Amount)
        ELSE c.Name + ' total'
        END AS totaltransactions,
    SUM(T.Amount) AS totalamount
FROM dbo.Tickets AS T
INNER JOIN Transport.Conductors AS c ON c.ConductorID = T.Conductor_ID
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,ServerDateTime) BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate
GROUP BY c.Name, T.Amount WITH ROLLUP;
```